# Need to fetch last word from the URL

Tags: javascript

I need to fetch the last word from the URL provided in the description. For example, there is a description which contains one URL and some other text and the last word in the URL changes from one page to other (using JavaScript).

I need to use the last word of the URL to fetch the records. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: Can you give an URL and a last word example to make it clearer, please?

Comment: Please provide an example url

Comment: What exactly you mean last word.Is it part after `#` , query string parameter value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the character that separates the word from the rest of the URL, you can use the `split` method that returns an array of strings. From that one, the last element is your word.

Eg for "&" as separator:

```
var str  = document.URL;
var n=str.split("&");
var word = n[n.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an example of your description and url.
My guess it is something like this:

```
blabla blablabla http://url.domain/bla/bla/bla.html bla bla bla
```

Then you split up your string with 'http'

```
str.split("http");
```

You get an array of 2 elements. You split the 2nd element on the first space encountered and then you get the last occurrence of / and the text that comes after the last / is your page.

ex:

```
function getString() {
    var str = "bla bla bla http://www.dell.com/index.html bla blabla"

    var sub = str.split("http")[1];
    var index = sub.indexOf(" ");
    sub = sub.substring(0,index);
    index = sub.lastIndexOf("/");
    sub = sub.substring(index+1,sub.lenght);
    alert(sub);
}
```